# How can I make part of the website not use https in web2py?

Tags: python, apache, https, ssl-certificate, web2py

Standard web2py deployment example demands https use sitewide. How can I skip it on some pages, or preferably use it only on admin interface? On some pages I need to serve some content from third party server, and this content is insecure and I can do nothing about it.

My current apache config for my site is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mywebsite.com
  ServerAlias mywebsitealias.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log common
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.cert
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.key

  WSGIProcessGroup web2py
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/web2py/wsgihandler.py
  WSGIPassAuthorization On

  <Directory /var/www/web2py>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
    <Files wsgihandler.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/static/(?:_[\d]+.[\d]+.[\d]+/)?(.*) \
        /var/www/web2py/applications/$1/static/$2

  <Directory /var/www/web2py/applications/*/static/>
    Options -Indexes
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hour"
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ssl-access.log common
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by replacing the   VirtualHost *:80 ... /VirtualHost
  bit with the code below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

 WSGIProcessGroup web2py
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/www-data/web2py/wsgihandler.py
  WSGIPassAuthorization On

  <Directory /home/www-data/web2py>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
    <Files wsgihandler.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log common
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

The http: stuff used to work fine with Apache 2.2 and then when Apache was upgraded to 2.4 the install script was changed in a way that makes everything https. The above is my mash up of the two scripts and seems to work for me though I'm not sure it's glitch free.

Comment: It is almost ok, except that appadmin now does not redirect to https.

Comment: On my server trying to access appadmin on http gives an error message "appadmin is disabled because insecure channel" which I presume is coming from web2py rather than Apache. You could try adding  `RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/(admin/.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]` which was suggested by Ariya Owam-aram. I have not actually tested that. There should be some new line characters in there which comment formatting does not seem to allow.